# Add margins not working

Tags: r

This code:

```
x=c(10,20,30,40,50)
y=c(17,30,37,50,56)
my.tbl=cbind(x,y,x-mean(x),y-mean(y),(x-mean(x))*(y-mean(y)),
          (x-mean(x))^2,(y-mean(y))^2)
colnames(my.tbl)=c("x","y","x-xbar","y-ybar",
                "(x-xbar)(y-ybar)","(x-xbar)^2","(y-ybar)^2")
my.tbl
addmargins(my.tbl)
```

Gives this error:

Error in array(values, dim = newdim, dimnames = newdimnames) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

Can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Using R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10), RStudio Version 0.98.1091

Comment: Does jazzurro's suggestion solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to R Help, "table or array. The function uses the presence of the "dim" and "dimnames" attributes of A.". Given that both RStudent and I spotted that you need dimnames. As you see below, `my.tbl` does not have `rownames`. You want to add rownames like the following. Then, you will have the right outcome.

```
dimnames(my.tbl)[[1]] <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
addmargins(my.tbl)

class(my.tbl)
#[1] "matrix"

str(my.tbl)
 #num [1:5, 1:7] 10 20 30 40 50 17 30 37 50 56 ...
 #- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 #..$ : NULL
 #..$ : chr [1:7] "x" "y" "x-xbar" "y-ybar" ...
```

Alternatively, you could probably do the following to assign rownames. At least, this is working on my MAC. By converting to table, you get rownames.

```
my.tbl2 <- as.table(my.tbl)

#class(my.tbl2)
#[1] "table"

#str(my.tbl2)
#table [1:5, 1:7] 10 20 30 40 50 17 30 37 50 56 ...
#- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#..$ : chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
#..$ : chr [1:7] "x" "y" "x-xbar" "y-ybar" ...

addmargins(my.tbl2)

#       x    y x-xbar y-ybar (x-xbar)(y-ybar) (x-xbar)^2 (y-ybar)^2  Sum
#A     10   17    -20    -21              420        400        441 1247
#B     20   30    -10     -8               80        100         64  276
#C     30   37      0     -1                0          0          1   67
#D     40   50     10     12              120        100        144  476
#E     50   56     20     18              360        400        324 1228
#Sum  150  190      0      0              980       1000        974 3294
```

Comment: I also tried this, but didn't work for me. And a matrix is also an array

Comment: @RStudent I see. I wonder what makes the difference between us. Let me consider this again

Comment: @RStudent I restarted R removing everything. The code is still working fine for me. I played with `my.tbl`. I added dimnames like this: `dimnames(my.tbl)[[1]] <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")`. Then, I tried `addmargins(my.tbl)`. Does this work for you?

Comment: It seems like `dimnames` cannot be NULL, doesn't it?

Comment: @jazzurro According to `?addmargins` `A: table or array.  The function uses the presence of the
          ‘"dim"’ and ‘"dimnames"’ attributes of ‘A’.`

Comment: But I still wonder why your version works for you but not so for me

Comment: @akrun long time. Thanks for the information. That is a note from this question for me. I wonder if you get the outcome using my code. I am still puzzled why RStudent and I have different results.

Comment: @jazzurro I just used `dimnames(my.tbl)[[1]] <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")` and everything worked perfect.  ie. you don't have to convert to `table` object.  By using `as.table`, I understand it automatically assign the `row.names`

Comment: @RStudent Not sure. Why this is the case. I wish I have an insight for this.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this with `rownames(my.tbl) <- 1:dim(my.tbl)[1]`:

```
> rownames(my.tbl) <- 1:dim(my.tbl)[1]
> addmargins(my.tbl)
      x   y x-xbar y-ybar (x-xbar)(y-ybar) (x-xbar)^2 (y-ybar)^2  Sum
1    10  17    -20    -21              420        400        441 1247
2    20  30    -10     -8               80        100         64  276
3    30  37      0     -1                0          0          1   67
4    40  50     10     12              120        100        144  476
5    50  56     20     18              360        400        324 1228
Sum 150 190      0      0              980       1000        974 3294
```

Comment: I just posted a message to you. I used `dimnames` and added rownames.

Comment: Glad to see that you also spotted the cause. For a good amount of investigation, +1.